# Disable oEmbed for a Single Shortcode or at Least All Internal Links

Tags: shortcode, oembed

Is there any way to disable the oEmbed functionality only for a specific call of the `do_shortcode()` function in just one script or if that is not possible can it be disabled for all the internal links on a site currently running WordPress 4.5.3?

I've tried using this line but it had no effect:

```
wp_oembed_remove_provider( 'http://www.example.com/*' );
```

So far the only thing that was somewhat useful is this line:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', array( $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'autoembed' ), 8 );
```

but as far as I know it disables all the oEmbed content and not just the internal links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we consider the question:

> can *post embeds* be disabled for all the internal links on a site currently running WordPress 4.5.3?

### The Short Story

If we want to disable *post embedding* of **internal links**, but allow it on external sites, then we can use:

```
/**
 * Disable post embeds for internal links but allow it on external sites
 */
add_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', function( $result, $url, $args )
{    
    if( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST ) ===  parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
        $result = false;

    return $result;

}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3 );
```

Here we check if the link is for the current host. This can be adjusted further to our needs.

We then don't need this filter callback:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    remove_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', 'wp_filter_pre_oembed_result', 10 );
} );
```

and probably others as well.

Note that the embeds are cached for 24 hours by default. Here are some [examples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/203558/26350) how to regenerate it.

*Sorry for the long part here below, but I decided to write it down, to better understand it ;-)*

### The Longer Version

When we paste the post url:

```
http://example.tld/hello-world
```

in the visual editor, then

```
[embed]http://example.tld/hello-world[/embed]
```

is sent to the `wp_ajax_parse_embed()` function via an ajax request, where it calls `$wp_embed->run_shortcode()`.

Similarly the content is filtered through the `$wp_embed->autoembed()` and `$wp_embed->run_shortcode()` via the `the_content` filter.

Both are based on the `WP_Embed::shortcode()` method <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a7a85856402272b465cde097b725653082db1884/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php#L126-L275)</sup>.

**Within the shortcode method**

If the data isn't cached, in the post meta, then `wp_oembed_get()` is fired up including the following sequence:

```
WP_oEmbed::get_html()
    WP_oEmbed::fetch()
        WP_oEmbed::_fetch_with_format()
            wp_safe_remote_get()
            wp_remote_retrieve_body()
```

and the data is fetched with a request to:

```
http://example.tld/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.tld%2Fhello-world%2F&
maxwidth=900&maxheight=1000&format=json
```

This rest endpoint, generates data with the `get_oembed_response_data()` function and also applies the `oembed_request_post_id` filter <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a7a85856402272b465cde097b725653082db1884/wp-includes/class-wp-oembed-controller.php#L68-L88)</sup>.

This filter was introduced in [#36767](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36767) in WordPress version 4.5.3.

By default *link discovery* is active. that means we would get an extra request with `wp_safe_remote_get()` to be able to parse the relevant `<link>` tags, from the remote site, to determine the provder's url:

```
http://example.tld/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.tld%2Fhello-world%2F
```

**The pre_oembed_result filter**

A new filter was also introduced in [#36767](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36767), within `WP_oEmbed::get_html()` <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a7a85856402272b465cde097b725653082db1884/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L336-L340)</sup>:

```
$pre = apply_filters( 'pre_oembed_result', null, $url, $args ); 

if ( null !== $pre ) { 
    return $pre; 
}
```

to avoid external HTTP requests for internal links. It will short-circuit the `wp_oembed_get()` if the filter returns anything else than `null`.

In core we now have:

```
add_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', 'wp_filter_pre_oembed_result', 10, 3 );
```

where the filter's callback `wp_filter_pre_oembed_result()` generates data with the `get_oembed_response_data()` function, just as for the embed rest endpoint. It's filterable through the `oembed_response_data` filter. The `get_oembed_response_data_rich()` callback is hooked into it with:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_response_data',   'get_oembed_response_data_rich', 10, 4 );
```

It contains the `get_post_embed_html()` function that generates the `<blockquote>`, `<script>` and `<iframe>` code.

**Disable internal post embeds**

To disable post embeds for internal links, our suggestion is therefore to make sure the `pre_oembed_result` filter returns `false` (different than `null`):

```
/**
 * Disable post embeds for internal links but allow it on external sites
 */
add_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', function( $result, $url, $args )
{    
    if( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST ) ===  parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
        $result = false;
    return $result;

}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3 );
```

where we return false as late as possible, hence we use a large *priority* like `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Then we don't need `wp_filter_pre_oembed_result()` callback to run, so we can also remove it with:

```
remove_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', 'wp_filter_pre_oembed_result', 10 );
```

where we have to remove it with the same priority as it was added with.

Another approach could be to use:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_request_post_id', '__return_false' );
```

This would mean that we get HTTP requests to the rest endpoint that will through an error because the post id isn't valid.

**Simple Testing**

Here's a way to test it. First we need an object instance of the `WP_Embed` class:

```
$e = new WP_Embed();
```

or use the global `$wp_embed` object. Then we setup the internal and external post links:

```
$internal = 'http://internal.tld/hello-world/';
$external = 'http://external.tld/hello-world/';
```

and run:

```
$internal_is_embeddable = $internal !== $e->run_shortcode( 
    sprintf( '[embed]%s[/embed]', 
    $internal 
);

$external_is_embeddable = $external !== $e->run_shortcode( 
    sprintf( '[embed]%s[/embed]', 
    $external 
);
```

We can also test it without shortcodes using:

```
$internal_is_embeddable = $internal !== $e->autoembed( $internal );
$external_is_embeddable = $external !== $e->autoembed( $external );
```

We just have to be aware of the oembed (post meta) cache and use e.g. a cache busting parameter for the test links. Here are some [examples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/203558/26350) how to regenerate it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the really detailed answer - everything works great, but it might be useful if you add in the short version that in order for this to work for older posts first the oEmbed cache must be cleared.

Comment: You're welcome, good to hear it worked for you. Thanks, I added a note on on the caching in the short version too. @SledgeHammer