# Wordpress and Youtube problem

Tags: youtube

I have problem that Youtube videos are not working on my page. I have done several ways to embed YT videos but nothing.

1. I tried to put just link in post and YT video doesn't show on final post. I even tried to insert YT link but that link is crossed and plugin for broken links is reporting there is problem with that link.
2. I tried to embed videos with tagDiv Composer plugin and they are not showing up. I tried to set channel id, channel playlist.
3. And lastly I installed plugin to insert playlist from YT via video id. That doesn't work either.

I thought it was problem with some plugin then I completely restored Wordpress to its default state. Problem is still here. So problem is that there is something that blocks YT videos from showing on Wordpress page. I even tried different browser.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but maybe it's an oembed cache issue. Have a look at the answer here for a solution to clear the oembed cache, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203537/how-can-i-clear-oembed-caches-for-youtube-on-posts-as-they-are-loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding an iFrame.
Go to the youtube video you're trying to post.
Click right > Copy embed code.

Paste it in the HTML editor on wordpress. It should work without a plug in.