# Block editor: Sandbox iframe shows outdated HTML

Tags: block-editor, embed, youtube

Even if users disable the popular [Lazy Load for Videos](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load-for-videos/) plugin and the frontend correctly resets videos so that videos are no longer lazy-loaded, the Gutenberg block does not get reset. Below screenshot shows how the iframe still includes the HTML of the deactivated plugin:

[image]

I cleared my browser cache and cookies, I ensured the oembed metadata caches are emptied, and I tried to clear more caches using commands from [How can I clear oEmbed caches for YouTube on posts as they are loaded](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203537/how-can-i-clear-oembed-caches-for-youtube-on-posts-as-they-are-loaded).

How can I ensure that the old HTML disappears in favor of the default Youtube embed behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WordPress (Gutenberg) block editor requests data from an oembed proxy endpoint, and that endpoint retrieves data using the [Transients API](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/). It seems that clearing all oembed caches doesn't also clear oembed *transient* caches.

The following database query to clear your oembed caches from the postmeta table is NOT sufficient:

```php
global $wpdb;
$meta_key_1 = "|_oembed|_%%";
$meta_key_2 = "|_oembed|_time|_%%";
$wpdb->query(
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( 
        "DELETE FROM `".$wpdb->postmeta."`
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE %s ESCAPE '|'
            OR `meta_key` LIKE %s ESCAPE '|'",
        $meta_key_1,
        $meta_key_2
    )
);
```

You'll also need to clear the transient caches from the options table, like so:

```php
$option_name_1 = "|_transient|_oembed|_%%";
$option_name_2 = "|_transient|_timeout|_oembed|_%%";
$wpdb->query(
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( 
        "DELETE FROM `".$wpdb->options."`
            WHERE `option_name` LIKE %s ESCAPE '|'
            OR `option_name` LIKE %s ESCAPE '|'",
        $option_name_1,
        $option_name_2
    )
);
```